# Merging three greyscale images into one rgb image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have three greyscale masks generated by OpenCV that filter in three specific colors. I want to be able to quickly merge them without looping through every pixel in the image (my application requires it to run in real-time) and get an output similar to this:

[image: Desired output]

I've been able to create the three masks separately, but they still need to be combined into one image, where each mask represents a different channel. The first mask would be the red channel, the second would be green, and the third blue.

Clarification: The masks are basically 1/3 of the final image I want to create. I need a way to interpolate them so that they don't end up being the same color in the output and becoming incomprehensible.

More details:
I want to avoid using lots of loops since the current filter takes 4 seconds to process a 272 by 154 image. The masks are just masks created using the `cv2.inRange` function.

I'm not very good with using numpy or OpenCV yet so any solution that can run reasonably fast (if it can process 15-20 fps it's totally usable) would be of great help.

Comment: You may use something like `bgr = cv2.merge((b, g, r))`. I suggests you to post the three masks, and some minimal code trying to solve it.

Comment: that or `np.dstack`, whichever you like more. if you're going the numpy route, try `numba`'s JIT on top of that. it has optimizable/specializable code for many core routines of numpy.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rotem has said, using `cv2.merge` to combine the three matrices into one bgr image seems to be one of the best solutions. It's really fast. Thanks!

```
bgr = cv2.merge((b, g, r))
```

I don't know how I didn't see it while reading the documentation. Oh well.

Answer (score -1):

Another way I used once

```
def merge_images(img1, img2, img3):
    img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    img3 = cv2.cvtColor(img3, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    img = np.concatenate((img1, img2, img3), axis=1)
    return img
```

Comment: this puts them all beside each other, right? so it does _not_ stack the color planes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).